# users command and find current active user not all logged in users

Tags: shell, command

I know 'users' command will list all logged in users in alphabetic order. How can I get the name of user currently active?

Answer (score 0):

Several ways.  The `id` command, the `USER` and `LOGNAME` variables.  The variables are not safe, they can be altered.  In Bash you can use `UID` to get the user id, and that is readonly.

Comment: I just need the name of user currently active. Few lines of shell command will be highly appreciated. I am very bad at scripting language.Please do help.

Comment: And yeah i am running these commands as root. So I don't know how 'id' command will help,, though 'users' command gives a list of all users. Can you please write some code to iterate this and print only the active username?

Comment: Sorry, I am misunderstanding.  What do you mean by "the active username" if you are running as root.  Do you mean the effective username or the real username - `id` will give both.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two ways to do this.

```
gawk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

OR

```
who
```

Comment: I am running these commands as root and 'users' command gives a list of all users. Can you please write some code to iterate this and print only the active username? OR any other way ?? That will be highly appreciated. I am very bad at scripting. Actually I have to add these lines of code in a shell script which I am executing with root permission, So basically all the commands will be automatically run by root.